# How to fill the space with Container in Column inside Row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Following is my code in Flutter.

```dart
class MyListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: _ListView(),
    );
  }
}

class _ListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return MyTile();
        }
    );
  }
}

class MyTile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("AAA"),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Text("BBB"),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Text("CCC\nDDD"),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("aaaa"),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output is following image.

[image]

But it is not what I want to draw.
I would like the blue container widget to fill the extra space like following image. Yellow text is my supplementary comment.

[image]

Then, I changed `width: 20,` to `width: double.infinity`, however it resulted in build error.

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

=======

**[Additional comment]**

I have deleted the `width` property like following.

```dart
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("aaaa"),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Then, the blue container is completely hidden. Probably the width becomes zero...

[image]

Comment: have you tried using mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignemnt?

Comment: @basudevnayak Thank you for your comment! Where should I insert `mainAlignment` or `crossAxisAlignment` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should expand your second column and use a stretch cross axis alignment:

```
class MyTile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Row(children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Text("AAA"),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text("BBB"),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text("CCC\nDDD"),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text("aaaa"),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have added a width:20 so this is static so try with the `Expanded`  widget and passed width using `MediaQuery`

```
return Container(
  height: 100,
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Text("AAA"),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Text("BBB"),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Text("CCC\nDDD"),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
         child:  Column(
           children: [
             Text("aaaa"),
             Expanded(
               child: Container(
                 color: Colors.blue,
                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       )
      ]
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have added my comment in my post. It doesn't work for me.. It make blue container hidden.

Comment: @ken kindly please recheck my answer i updated my answer

Comment: It results in error... `A RenderFlex overflowed by 51 pixels on the right.` Probably, the width you specified is the width of mobile device, but it is too large for the blue container.

Comment: @ken please recheck my answer it should work